# NIS failing to bind

Tags: centos, nis, rpc, networkmanager, yp

I have a bunch of machines which authenticate via NIS to a central server. I just bought a new CentOS 6.2 client machine, and it can't authenticate.

The following is a list of *the classics* people get wrong/forget when dealing with NIS:

**1) The client machine can ping the server (and ssh in)**

Tested using

```
    ping swordfish 

    ping <ip address>
```

Both of which generate an appropriate response

**2) A `ypbind` process is running on the client**

Tested by doing

```
ps -e | grep ypbind
3172 ?        00:00:00 ypbind
```

**3) `/etc/yp.conf` is formatted correctly and contains the correct details**

**4)The firewall is off**
So that's hopefully not the problem

**5) The `service` starter *thinks* everything is OK**

```
    /sbin/service ypbind restart

    Shutting down NIS service:                                 [  OK  ]
    Starting NIS service:                                      [  OK  ]
    Binding NIS service:
    .....                                                      [  OK  ]
```

**The Problem**

- There's no RPC binding as far as I can tell

  ```
  /usr/sbin/rpcinfo -p # no ypbind programs
  ```
- There are no binding files in `/var/yp/binding/`
- If I view the message log in `/var/logs/messages` then the following type of report is generated every time I restart the ypbind service

  ```
  Sep  7 14:21:34 localhost ypbind: NIS domain: whaleshark, NIS server:
  ```

Where whaleshark is the name of the NIS domain, but apparently it has no info on the NIS server? Running ypwhich yields;

`ypwhich: Can't communicate with ypbind`

Any thoughts or steps I could take would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to insecure technology that should not be deployed in a production environment. (NIS)

Comment: @AndrewB I don't believe it is impossible to deploy NIS in a secure fashion. I just think it is very hard. Many times recommending an alternative is the right thing to do.

Comment: @kasperd Agreed, I discussed this on meta and we worked out where my thought process was wrong. I'll flag this for reopening if it gets closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ha - I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but just realized the NetworkManager daemon is running, which apparently is blocking when the network interfaces are set to not use the NetworkManager.

Simply running

```
service NetworkManager stop
```

And then restarting fixed everything. Hopefully this will help other people out - I saw a bunch of similar looking symptoms online but no-one mentioned the NetworkManager at all.

Comment: This fixed my NIS problem with CentOS 6 running as a Docker container. service NetworkManager stop && service ypbind restart

Comment: Same here. I was looking for a while and would've never thought of checking to see if NM was running.

Comment: Running the command `service NetworkManager stop` on my centos 6 nis client did fix the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue, and stopping networkmanager didnt help. 
After trying out different tricks, i found an interesting workaround. in my case when there was a process dbus-daemon and due to some reason it was consuming lot of CPU, and as soon as i stopped the dbus-daemon process and restarted ypbind service it worked. Please give it a try this, if nothing works. Hope it is helpful !

Answer (score 0):

Try this command before starting ypbind service:

```
authconfig --update --nisdomain=<nis domain name> --nisserver=<nis server name> --enablenis
```

Answer (score -2):

You stop the NetworkManager and start ypbind to let ypbind get the binding files.
You can start the NetworkManager once it has got the binding files.